# Android: searchview to search specific strings variables

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview

I am developing an android app where I use a `SearchView` widget to search in a custom `ListView` of users data (image + Name and several textfields). The problem is that when I type a query it only searches through the names. Is there any way to tell the `SearchView` widget to search through the other strings in the `ListView` cells?

Thank you in advance.

The code below is what I currently have in the activity with search in actionbar:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.redirect_user, menu);
        MenuItem menuitem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        searchItem = (SearchView) menuitem.getActionView();

        int id = searchItem.getContext().getResources()
                .getIdentifier("android:id/search_src_text", null, null);
        TextView textView = (TextView) searchItem.findViewById(id);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        searchItem.setBackgroundColor(color.white);

        searchItem.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                FiltreActivity.getAdapter().getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

/**
 * Shows a list that can be filtered in-place with a SearchView in non-iconified <span id="IL_AD1" class="IL_AD">mode</span>.
 */
public class SearchViewFilterMode extends Activity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    SearchView mSearchView;
    private ListView mListView;

    private final String[] mStrings = Cheeses.sCheeseStrings;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);

        setContentView(R.layout.searchview_filter);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                mStrings));
        mListView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        setupSearchView();
    }

    private void setupSearchView() {
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true); 
        mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
            mListView.clearTextFilter();
        } else {
            mListView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's your idea here?